# Processing: how to make mouseClicked function vary from click times?

Tags: input, click, processing

As title, what I want to realize with Processing:

There are classical circles running across on the screen, then:

The first time you click the mouse all the circles freeze(stop moving);

The second time you click the mouse you draw a new circle with your mouse position.

The problem is: How to tell the computer to act differently? After all, they are all clicks, seem the same to the computer.

I am thinking about to detect if something already happened in Processing(like the first click). if it cannot be done, can I use javascript to do so? I want to put it on the browser anyway.

Does anybody know? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume it's mostly up to how you envision the interaction. It can be as simple or as complex as you see fit.

If it helps, here are couple of ideas:

1.Use different actions for different [mouse buttons](http://processing.org/reference/mouseButton.html) (e.g. regular/left click spawns a new circle, right click moves existing circles to a desired location):

```
void draw(){
  color bg = color(0);
  if(mousePressed){
    if(mouseButton == LEFT )  bg = color(192,0,0);
    if(mouseButton == CENTER) bg = color(0,192,0);
    if(mouseButton == RIGHT)  bg = color(0,0,192);
  }
  background(bg);  
}
```

2.Use button and key combinations. For example a `SHIFT+CLICK` does a separate action rather than the default:

```
void draw(){
  color bg = color(0);//default
  if(mousePressed && keyPressed && keyCode == SHIFT) bg = color(255,192,0);//shift+click
  background(bg);  
}
```

3.Keep track of clicks and use the click number a cue to different states:

```
int numClicks = 0;

void draw(){
  background(numClicks*25);  
}
void mousePressed(){
  numClicks++;
  if(numClicks > 10) numClicks = 0;//reset after 10 'states'/different clicks
}
```

This, as an interaction is probably less intuitive though. In my opinion, the simpler things are (especially for the user), the better.

HTH

Comment: hey can i detect if something already happened in Processing(like the first click)? if not, can i use javascript to do so ? i want to put it on the browser anyway.

Comment: I follow Processing questions, so me again :) I'm not what you mean by "something already happened" ? If you want to keep track of the number of clicks, that's what the example above (with `numClicks` does). The code works in Processing.js as well. The easiest way to test is to paste that snippet on [Sketch.Processing](http://sketch.processing.org/) and try it. There are other Processing web 'playgrounds' like [SketchPatch](http://sketchpatch.net/), [HasCanvas](http://hascanvas.com/) or [SketchPad](http://sketchpad.cc/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking "How can I keep track of state." That is, to know whether to "freeze" or to "draw circle."

You can do this with a simple variable:

```
boolean freezeState = false;


void mousePressed(){

 if (freezeState == false){
    freezeState = true;

   // call method to freeze circles

 else if (freezeState == true){
   freezeState = false;

   // call method to draw circle
}
```

Comment: The `if (freezeState == false){
    freezeState = true;

   // call method to freeze circles

 else if (freezeState == true){
   freezeState = false;
` can also be written as `freezeState = !freezeState` - the typical way you'd 'toggle' a boolean.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza - Yes, thanks. I unrolled it because the OP doesn't seem to have much experience yet and the verbose approach is perhaps easier to grasp.